# AWS CLI dynamoDB How to pass a variable to get-item --key map

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm trying to loop over a list of userIds to retrieve records from a dynamoDB table using AWS CLI.

```
// list.txt

abcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456
bbcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456
cbcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456
dbcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456
ebcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456
```

I ran the `get-item` aws command to retrieve a single record:

```
$ aws dynamodb get-item --table-name "fake-table" --key '{"userId": {"S": "abcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456"}}'
```

It gave me what I wanted:

```
{
    "Item": {

        ...

        "userId": {
            "S": "abcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456"
        },

        "data": { ... }
    }
}
```

I'm now trying to loop over `list.txt` to pass each id as a variable to the `--key` option which I understand to be a map and in the form of json.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html

My script looks like this:

```
while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
    (aws dynamodb get-item --table-name "fake-table" --key '{"userId": {"S": $LINE}}') >> output.txt
done < list.txt
```

It threw this error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--key': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 22 (char 21)
JSON received: {"userId": {"S": $$LINE}}
abcdefghijklmnop1234567890123456
```

I tried formatting the raw list so the userIds are wrapped in single quotation marks and received the same error.

1. How can I pass a variable into the map?

I would also like to extend the search to only return records for userIds that have data.

2. How would I extend my `get-item` search to check that data is not equal to `{}`?

I am trying to do this in the command-line to learn it.

I am also intending to do this in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It turned out to be the single quotation marks as @MilanCermak pointed out.
2. The purpose of the loop was to pull relevant user records form a list (total 12,000) but querying the database each time was too time consuming. It was faster to pull all (550,000) dynamoDB records and manipulate them with a python script.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "fake-table" \
  --projection-expression "userId" \
  --max-items 550000 --page-size 90 --region xx-xxx-1 \
  | python reformat_list.py > results.csv
```

I loved this problem 0_0

Answer (score 3):

The single quotes are preventing your shell (I'm assuming bash or similar) to expand the `$LINE` variable. Instead, they are preserving it as a literal value. See the Quoting section in [bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Try enclosing the whole thing in double quotes, slash-escaping those you need to format the JSON value:

```sh
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name "fake-table" --key "{\"userId\": {\"S\": $LINE}}" >> output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much @MilanCermak :)